# How to use the directory construct in gradle-ospackage-plugin?

Tags: gradle, rpm

I'm using the gradle-ospackage-plugin provided by Netflix (https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin), which lets me easily create RPM packages containing the outputs of my project.

I want my RPM to create a few empty directory when installed. In an old-fashioned rpm spec I would have done this:

```
%dir /var/opt/myapp/data
```

I tried using this:

```
ospackage {
    packageName = 'foo'
}
buildRpm {
     directory('/var/opt/myapp/data', 640)
}
```

And "gradlew buildRpm" does its job fine. When calling `rpm -q -filesbypkg -p <myrpm>`, I get this, seemingly correct, output:

```
foo          /var/opt/myapp/data
```

But, when installing, it fails:

```
[vagrant@guest1 share]$ sudo rpm -i foo-0.0.1.noarch.rpm
error: unpacking of archive failed on file ./var/opt/myapp/data: cpio: Archive file not in header
```

I don't see:

1. Why it tries to install the directory in "." rather than the root, and
2. Why even that fails.

Any hints would be most welcome, since the Plugin-Rpm.md file is not very forthcoming on the issue of directories.

Comment: You might rather want to ask this question on the plugin's GitHub page.

Comment: I did, but got no response, so after a few weeks I decided to try my luck here. Fingers crossed that someone else has tried this. =)

Comment: I can have a look at it later this week. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Still no reply to either the Issue on GitHub or in the Google group...

Comment: I dont know the answer myself but as an alternative, you can execute a pre or post install script which creates the empty directory like you want.  Ex: postInstall file('postinstall.sh')

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm currently doing. Forgot to mention it in the question.

Answer (score 3):

the `createDirectoryEntry` and `addParentDirs` flags control this.

```
into('/mydir/'){
    fileMode 0550
    from ( 'src/mydir'){ 
          addParentDirs false 
          createDirectoryEntry true 
    } 
}
```

Manually create directories like this:

```
directory( '/space/tmpdir' ,0775);
```

See [the gradle-ospackage-plugin page](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/blob/gradle-2.2/Plugin-Rpm.md), there are a lot of Q&A about this issue on that site.

Note: There is a defect and workaround comments [here](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/issues/14).

The directory statement alone works fine for me, possibly its been fixed since your post.